# How to set hardware breakpoint by value?

Tags: ida, windows, debugging, hardware, breakpoint

I want to set in IDA breakpoint when a specific value is written on the stack.

I know how to set hardware breakpoint, but I can set it only by address.

Answer (score 1):

You simply cannot. There are no mechanisms by which you can break execution on a specific value write. You'll have to use any other mechanisms, probably a memory breakpoint, and a conditional check of what's at the top of the stack.

Comment: How can I set memory breakPoint and check the top of stack?

Comment: That'd be slow, but you can set a conditional memory breakpoint in IDA on stack pages.

Comment: Can you please tell me how do I set that? I know only on breakpoint I set on code or by address(hardware) i domt know about memory breakpoint in ida  on stack pages.